# Can you do an inner select with Subsonic?

Tags: c#, sql, subsonic, inner-join

This is my sql query: subsonic version 2.1.0.0  No Linq (.net 2.0)

```
select
(
  select Title from MenuTranslation mnu2 where
  mnu2.languageid = 1 and mnu2.menuelementid = menutranslation.menuelementid
)as BaseTitle, *
from menutranslation
inner join menuelement on menuelement.id = menutranslation.menuelementid
where menuelementid
in (select id from menuelement where parentid = 4)
and languageid = 2
```

Comment: Which version of Subsonic? Are you using SqlQuery or LINQ?

Comment: @Pieter: you need to highlight the code section and then click on the "code" button (010 101) in the toolbar to properly format code sections!

Comment: Ok done, can you give me a sign
thx

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time - however you can run IN queries with a SELECT - not subqueries however.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the inlineQuery class where you generate the sql yourself to accomplish what you are going after